# Does Serilog.Sinks.Console sink get any benefits from wrapping to Serilog.Sinks.Async sink?

Tags: serilog

I using `Serilog` inside my aspnet core app for logging. And i need to write log events to console pretty frequently (300-500 events per second). I run my app inside docker container and procces console logs using orchestrator tools.

So my question: should i use `Async` wrapper for my `Console` sink and will i get any benefits from that? 
I read the documentation (https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-async), but can't understand is it actual for `Console` sink or not.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `Async` Sink takes the already-captured `LogEvent` items and shifts them to a single background processor from multiple foreground threads using a `ConcurrentQueue` Producer/Consumer collection. In general that's a good thing for stable throughput esp with that throughput of events.

Also if sending to >1 sink, shifting to a background thread which will be scheduled as necessary focusing on that workload (i.e., paths propagating to sinks being in cache) can be good if you have enough cores available and/or Sinks block even momentarily.

Having said that, to base anything of this information is premature optimization.

---

Console sinks and their ability to ingest efficiently without blocking if you don't put an `Async` in front, always Depends a lot - for example, hosting environments typically synthesize a `stdout` that buffers efficiently. When that works well, adding an `Async` in front of the Console sink is merely going to prolong object lifetimes without much benefit vs allowing each thread submit to the Console sink directly.

---

So, it depends - IME feeding everything to `Async` and doing all processing there (e.g. writing to a buffered file, emitting every `.5s` (perhaps to a sidecar process that forwards to your log store)) can work well. The bottom line is that a good load generator rig is a very useful thing for any high throughput app. Once you have one, you can experiment - I've seen 30% throughput gains from reorganizing the exact same output and how it's scheduled (admittedly I also switched to Serilog during that transition - you're unlikely to see anything of that order).

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer!

Comment: Very good [blog post from Rick Strahl which covers lots of this ground esp in the context of ASP.NET Core](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2018/Dec/31/Dont-let-ASPNET-Core-Default-Console-Logging-Slow-your-App-down) - doesn't change the fundamental point I'm trying to get across above: doing the legwork to make it possible to measure is key.

Comment: When i tested serilog file vs console logging performance, i also disabled standard netcore logging first. It increased performance of test app near 2-3 times.